# WIndows Phone C# change content button AFTER CLICK

Tags: c#, button

I'm starting my adventure with C# and writting apps on Windows Phone, but I stucked a little. I am writting an easy game noughts and crosses.

I have a button:

```
 <Button Content=" " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="126" Margin="37,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Click="a0"/>
```

And I wish that after clicking the content would change to X, like

```
public void a0(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    a0.Content = "X";
}
```

But I know that's impossible. How can I do this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [x:Name Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you are going to use it, assign the name to the button.

```
x:Name = "btnA0"
```

Later in button click event handler:

```
btnA0.Content = "ButtonNewContent";
```

Answer (score 2):

`sender` parameter is the object that triggers the event. So you can use it to access your button:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
if(btn != null)
{ 
   btn.Content = "X";
}
```